# Неверная кодировка при развертывании проекта на хостинг

Tags: jsp, mysql, servlet, java

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема. Я написал приложение на Java с использованием MySQL без фреймворков. На каждой jsp странице указываю кодировку utf-8 и для servlet'ов также, для response и request тоже. На моем компьютере все работает правильно, если я заполняю какую-либо форму на русском, все нормально и в базе данные также отображаются на русском, но стоит только задиплоить проект на хостинге - вместо русского получаются иероглифы. Версия tomcat & MySQL на хостинге та же, что и у меня. 
В чем проблема? Также да, при подключении к базе в url указываю use names 'utf8'.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть проблема в том, что на сервере прописана кодировка по умолчанию windows-1251
Надо явно указать серверу Вашу кодировку. В яве я ноль, но думаю тут без разницы - в .htaccess дописывается кодировка

> AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

и все работает, пробуйте.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Тоже самое, все равно кракозябли всякие.

Comment: А сами файлы в какой кодировке? Значит файлы в win-1251бь надо сделать utf

Comment: Сами файлы тоже в utf-8, т.к в eclipse указано, что кодировка JSP utf-8. Мне просто не понятно, почему у меня нормально работает, а на хостинге нет, ведь ничего не меняю.

Comment: Если у Вас нормально, а на хостинге нет - вывод один: разная конфигурация серверов, мой скромный опыт показывает, что проблемы такого рода именно а) кодировка сервера не та, с которой работает скрипт. б) файлы скрипта в кодировке, которая не совпадает с кодировкой сайта.
В php я бы еще посоветовал сделать что-то вроде
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
насчет явы не знаю, думаю тоже как то можно насильно заставить выдавать мускул в нужной кодировке данные.

Comment: я делаю SET NAMES utf8 только указываю это как параметр url по которому подключаюсь к базе

Comment: Тогда не знаю. Пахнет чудесами, но я в них не верю =)

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте Ozim.
Можно, конечно, в начале каждого файла jsp прописать следующий программный код, с нужной Вам кодировкой:
<%request.setCharacterEncoding("windows-1251");%>
По крайней мере у меня так работает.
С уважением, Евгений.

Comment: это не мой вопрос =)
p.s. лучше, все-таки (имхо), прописать в одном файле (конфиг файле, например) и инклюдить во все остальные. или на яве такого нет?